# How to monitor Mongo databases and Cloud servers?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, amazon-cloudwatch, dbachecks

We have mongo databases installed in AWS and Azure based servers. We need to monitor the Mongo databases and Cloud servers on daily basis. Is there any way to healthcheck the databases and servers ?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to the site, what is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/free-monitoring/) Starting in `version 4.0`, **`MongoDB (Community Edition)`** offers free Cloud monitoring for standalones and replica sets.

Free monitoring provides information about your deployment, including:

- Operation Execution Times
- Memory Usage
- CPU Usage
- Operation Counts

By default, you can enable/disable free monitoring during runtime using [db.enableFreeMonitoring()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.enableFreeMonitoring/#db.enableFreeMonitoring) and [db.disableFreeMonitoring()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.disableFreeMonitoring/#db.disableFreeMonitoring).

You can also enable or disable free monitoring during [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) startup using either:

- the configuration file setting [cloud.monitoring.free.state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#cloud.monitoring.free.state)
  or
- the command-line option [--enableFreeMonitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-enablefreemonitoring)

Once you enable free monitoring, it remains enabled until you disable it.